# Updating a column in database using dropdown with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I've been looking for a basic dropdown sample for updating a field in database, and I can't find any. I did my own code but it won't work. Can someone give me sample?
Here's my code if ever someone could help me what to do with this cause honestly, there's no output after i tried to run this code.

My view:

```
<select name="myselect">
<option value="one" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one'); ?> >Pending</option>
<option value="two" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'two' , TRUE); ?> >For Payment</option>
 <?php echo form_dropdown('status', $options, 'two'); ?>
 </select>
```

And this is my model:

```
 public function editstatus($status,$roomid)
{   
$query = "UPDATE reservation SET status='$status' WHERE reservation_id='$roomid'";  
$this->db->query($query, array($status,$roomid));
}
```

And my controller:

```
 public function viewstatus() {

  $data['status']=$this->loginmod->editstatus();
 $this->load->view('viewstatus',$data);


 }
```

Please someone help me..

Answer (score 0):

I guess by update you mean data is already available in the DB table and you want to update the record. for that you need to pass the primary / unique key to your controller/model and then pass to your update query. for update query a primary/unique is a must. Here is the sample

```
<form method="post" action="<?=site_url('controller/function/'.$unique_key_passed)?>">
```

and on the controller function end;

```
function some_function()
{
$unique_key=$this->uri->segment(2);
$this->db->update('table_name',$data_to_be_updated,$unique_key);
}
```

here unique key in the update query will be checked in table. if available, record will be updated by $data_to_be_updated.

hope you got some basic view of the picture.